# Не срабатывает onClickListener

Tags: android, kotlin, setonclicklistener

```
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

    val view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.page, container, false)

    return view
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    val radioOne = view.findViewById<RadioButton>(R.id.radio_one)
    val radioTwo = view.findViewById<RadioButton>(R.id.radio_two)
    val radioThree = view.findViewById<RadioButton>(R.id.radio_three)
    val radioFour= view.findViewById<RadioButton>(R.id.radio_four)
    var score = 0
    val radioList = arrayOf(radioOne, radioTwo, radioThree, radioFour)
    val finishButton = view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.finishButton)
    val correctAnswerNumber: Int
    val questionText = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.questionText)

    val args = arguments
    if (args != null) {
        questionText.text = args.getString(PageTaker.KEY_QUESTION_TEXT)
        radioOne.text = args.getString(PageTaker.KEY_ANSWER_ONE)
        radioTwo.text = args.getString(PageTaker.KEY_ANSWER_TWO)
        radioThree.text = args.getString(PageTaker.KEY_ANSWER_THREE)
        radioFour.text = args.getString(PageTaker.KEY_ANSWER_FOUR)
        correctAnswerNumber = args.getInt(PageTaker.KEY_CORRECT_ANSWER)
        when {
            radioList[correctAnswerNumber].isChecked -> score = 1
            else -> score = 0
        }
        finishButton.setOnClickListener { View.OnClickListener {
            Toast.makeText(context, score.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        }

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Args are null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, куда копать. Пока вообще непонятно, тк при нажатии на кнопку finishButton не отображается ничего.

Код вызывается в onCreateView (Fragment).

json-файл

```
{"pages":[{
  "questionText":"Что такое преобразователь частоты?",
  "answerOne": "Электротехническое устройство, предназначенное для преобразования электроэнергии промышленной амплитуды и частоты в электроэнергию с регулируемой амплитудой и частотой",
  "answerTwo": "что-то",
  "answerThree": "То же самое, что тиристорный преобразователь напряжения",
  "answerFour": "ничего",
  "correctAnswer": "1"},
{"questionText": "Вопрос 2",
  "answerOne": "Неправильный ответ 1 (2)",
  "answerTwo": "Неправильный ответ 2 (2)",
  "answerThree": "Правильный ответ (2)",
  "answerFour": "Неправильный ответ 3 (2)",
  "correctAnswer": "3"},
{"questionText":"Вопрос 3",
  "answerOne": "Неправильный ответ 1 (3)",
  "answerTwo": "Неправильный ответ 2 (3)",
  "answerThree": "Правильный ответ (3)",
  "answerFour": "Неправильный ответ 3 (3)",
  "correctAnswer": "3"}]}
```

Comment: Вы задаете вопрос, предоставляя огромное количество лишней информации. А Ваш вопрос формулируется как: "При нажатии на кнопку не появляется тоаст" и код.

Comment: если проблема решена - примите ответ, пожалуйста

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте переписать код следующим образом:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    ...
    val args = arguments
    if(args != null){
        ...
        finishButton.setOnClickListener { 
            Toast.makeText(context, score.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Args are null!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

И посмотрите на результат.

... - сюда вставляйте свой код.

Пояснение. 
У Вашей проблемы может быть две причины:

1. Вы выбрали неверный метод жизненного цикла. `onViewCreated` точно правильный, потому советую перенести в него.
2. аргументы фрагмента равны null. Для этого добавляем дополнительный тоаст. Если ошибка в этом, то она станет очевидной при запуске.

P.s. Скорее всего, ошибка кроется здесь:

```
    finishButton.setOnClickListener { 
        View.OnClickListener { Toast.makeText(context, score.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show() }
    }
```

Здесь `View.OnClickListener` совершенно лишний. Почему:

Есть два варианта функции `setOnClickListener`

1. `setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener listener)`
   Принимает на вход объект, наследующий интерфейс `View.OnClickListener`.
   Вызывается с **круглыми** скобками.
2. `setOnClickListener(listener: (View) -> Unit)`
   Принимает на вход функцию, существует только для Kotlin (не будем сейчас углубляться в детали, почему, просто в Java такого нет).
   Вызывается с **фигурными** скобками.

То есть переписать Ваш код следует так:

```
finishButton.setOnClickListener { 
    Toast.makeText(context, score.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show() 
}
```

Comment: Тоаст, срабатывающий при args = null не появляется. При использовании onViewCreated на экране вообще нет ничего.

Comment: @Larian Вот теперь добавьте, пожалуйста, в вопрос новые версии `onViewCreated` и `onCreateView`

Comment: Добавил новые .

Comment: @Larian кажется, понял, что не так, добавил информацию в ответ

Comment: Большое спасибо, кнопка заработала. Только почему-то игнорируется ветвь radioList[correctAnswerNumber].isChecked -> score = 1, то есть всегда выполняется ветвь else

Comment: @Larian проверяйте, что у Вас там лежит, в этом листе, какой `correctAnswerNumber`

Comment: Посмотрел. Почему-то там null вместо числа. Не понимаю, почему. С остальными переменными ведь проблем нет.

Comment: @Larian тут уже только проверять, корректно ли Вы его храните.

Comment: Добавил json файл. Пробовал хранить correctAnswer как целое число. Результат тот же.